# ModuleNotFoundError how to import my flie in django.view

Tags: python, django

I want to import my python files in django app

```
import myfile

dct = myfile.myfunc()

def index(request):
  context = dct
  return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', context)

>>>ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
```

Answer (score 0):

add empty `__init__.py` file in folder, where is `myfile.py`

Comment: __init__.py is exist in folder
appfolder
-templates
-static
-__init__.py
-views.py
-myfile.py
.
.